# C conflicting types caused by macro

Tags: c, arm, gcc-warning

I'm building some code that used to compile properly with an older version of Rowley Crossworks for ARM version 2. Now trying to compile the application with Crossworks for ARM version 4, the following header file causes the compiler to throw the following errors:

> conflicting types for 'UEZMemAlloc'
>  conflicting types for
>   'UEZMemRealloc'

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * File:  uEZMemory.h
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Description:
 *     uEZ Memory Allocation (thread safe) routines
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#ifndef _UEZ_MEMORY_H_
#define _UEZ_MEMORY_H_

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * uEZ(R) - Copyright (C) 2007-2010 Future Designs, Inc.
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file is part of the uEZ(R) distribution.  See the included
 * uEZLicense.txt or visit http://www.teamfdi.com/uez for details.
 *
 *    *===============================================================*
 *    |  Future Designs, Inc. can port uEZ(tm) to your own hardware!  |
 *    |             We can get you up and running fast!               |
 *    |      See http://www.teamfdi.com/uez for more details.         |
 *    *===============================================================*
 *
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Includes:
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "uEZTypes.h"

#ifndef UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY
#define UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY    0
#endif
#ifndef UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY_FAIL_CALLBACK
#define UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY_FAIL_CALLBACK 0
#endif

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Prototypes:
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void UEZMemInit(void);
void *UEZMemAlloc(TUInt32 aSize);
void *UEZStackMemAlloc(TUInt32 aSize);
void UEZMemFree(void *aMemory);
void *UEZMemRealloc(void *aMemory, TUInt32 aSize); //NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
void *UEZMemAllocPermanent(TUInt32 aSize);
void *UEZPlatformMemAllocPermanent(TUInt32 aSize);

#if UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY_FAIL_CALLBACK
void UEZMemFailedCallback(void);
#endif
#if UEZ_MEM_CHECK_MEMORY
TUInt32 UEZMemGetSize(void *aMemory);
TUInt32 UEZMemGetNumBlocks(void);
#endif

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Macros:
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Provide standard C compatible routines
#define malloc(a)           UEZMemAlloc(a)
#define free(a)             UEZMemFree(a)
#define realloc(a, b)       UEZMemRealloc(a, b)


#endif // _UEZ_MEMORY_H_

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * End of File:  uEZMemory.h
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

It looks to me like the newer compiler is now irritated about:

```
#define malloc(a)           UEZMemAlloc(a)
#define realloc(a, b)       UEZMemRealloc(a, b)
```

The uEZ library I'm using has [documentation here.](http://www.teamfdi.com/uez/docs/u_e_z_memory_8h.html#ab8b25cd8f16d4a6552afe4e65c4f082d) It seems to be indicate it was done on purpose. Has the gcc compiler/preprocessor gotten more picky over time? Is there a way to avoid these errors? Rowley Crossworks for ARM uses GCC.

Comment: With `UEZMemAlloc(TUInt32 aSize);`, `#define malloc(a)           UEZMemAlloc(a)` and `malloc(size_t size);`, is there some reason code does not use `UEZMemAlloc(size_t aSize);`?

Comment: "Has the gcc compiler/preprocessor gotten more picky over time?" --> Perhaps on this compile `TUInt32` differs from `size_t`?

Comment: @chux This is library code that we purchased years ago. They provided the malloc() define.

Comment: The library defines `TUInt32` as `unsigned long`

Comment: "the following header file causes the compiler to throw the following errors".  Idea: it is not the header file, alone, causing the issue.  It is the header file and some *.c code or another header.  More code is needed to see what conflicts with what.

Comment: What does the library define `size_t` as?

Comment: @chux It doesn't. It appears to be using the ARM gcc standard headers for that. The library doesn't appear to redefine `size_t`

Comment: It appears to be triggered when `main.c` includes `uEZ.h`. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: What is the command line of gcc? what compiling options is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify a Config_Build.h file which caused the compile to NOT change the types of some standard C types.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.